# (Why is the ) Excel Current Cell Highlight Vanishing

Tags: excel, vba

I've got some very simple code in Excel 2013 that hides a few columns and sorts some records in a table. For some reason, it also hides the current cell highlight.

Not sure if it is the code or just an excel bug.  Any ideas why?

```
If ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True Then ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
wsDailyCheckDump.Range("$B:$H, $J:$Q, $T:$W, $Y:$Z, $AB:$AB, $AD:$AK, $AM:$AN, $AS:$AV, $AZ:$BF, $BG:$BK, $BM:$DC, $DJ:$DL, $DN:$DR").Columns.Hidden = True


Set rngSortA = tblDailyCheck.ListColumns(49).Range
Set rngSortB = tblDailyCheck.ListColumns(18).Range
Set rngSortC = tblDailyCheck.ListColumns(9).Range

With tblDailyCheck.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add rngSortA, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add rngSortB, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add rngSortC, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Apply
End With

wsDailyCheckDump.Range("$X$5").Offset(1, 0).Select '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True


Set rngA = wsDailyCheckDump.Range("$A$5").End(xlToRight)
rngA.Select
Set rngA = ActiveCell
rngA.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Select` moves the active (current) cell. You have to save the location of `ActiveCell` into a range variable and `.Select` that variable just before your subroutine end.

Comment: I've updated the main section, have assigned ActiveCell to a range and then .select'd it, but still nothing, the cell highlight is still not visible until I switch to a different tab and back.